# Derivative of $ y = \ln(x^2 + y^2)$? Why is $d(y^2)/dx = 0$?

Tags: derivatives

The answer is

$y' = 2x/(x^2+y^2-2y)$

or

$y' = 2x/(x^2+y^2)$

At wolfram it says $d(y^2)/dx = 0$?

http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP44041daf8be8cc1i97i900005a2dbcggic267i1c?MSPStoreType=image/png&s=32&w=560&h=716

Comment: Please see my update, I may have misunderstood your question, but added an update correction for implicit differentiation! Sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have:

$$f(x, y) = \ln(x^2 + y^2)$$

Note that the $y$ term is missing here, and using the chain rule with $\ln$, we get:

$$d/dx ~(\ln(x^2 + y^2)) = \dfrac{1}{x^2 + y^2}~d/dx~ (x^2 + y^2) = \dfrac{1}{x^2 + y^2}(2x+0) =\dfrac{2x}{x^2 + y^2}$$

This is your second result, but I do not believe this is what you wanted.

**Update**

If we are doing implicit differentiation of your original expression, we have:

$$dy/dx = \dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}(2x + 2y ~ dy/dx)$$

Solving for $dy/dx$ yields:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{2x}{x^2+y(y-2)}$$

This is your first result. If you wanted to see this in WA, try [*this*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+derivative+with+respect+to+x+%28y+%3D+ln%28x%5E2%2B+y%5E2%29%29).

Comment: Can you explain why d y^2/dx = 0 not = 2y y' ?

Comment: I saw it as a simple implicit differentiation problem;  the title does say $y=...$

Comment: The two different answers are confusing.  The first matches the implicit differentiation assumption...

Comment: @User58220: I added an update correction! Thanks for your comment! Regards

Comment: Great answer, and follow up! +1 ;-)